# Conformals mappings

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

> Find the conformal mapping of the disk $\left|z\right| <2$ to the right half plane, $\operatorname{Re}(z)> 0$, such that $w(0) = 1$, $\operatorname{Arg}(w'(0)) = \frac{\pi}{2}$.

I have tried the following:

First transform radio disk $2$ to unit disk with $w_1(z)=\frac{z}{2}$
Now, I have to go from the unit circle to the right plane $\operatorname{Re}(w)> 0$ use $w_{2}(z) = - \frac{z + 1}{z-1}$.

Then the mapping that sends us from the circle of radius $2$ will be $g(z)=w_2(w_1(z))$.

Is this correct? And what do I have to do to get that $w(0) = 1$, $\operatorname{Arg}(w'(0)) = \frac{\pi}{2}$?

I would appreciate your help.

Advance:

I have to do the mapping that I need is $g(z)=-\frac{z+2}{z-2}$
I have to $g´ (0) = 1 $
Now, for me to realize that $Arg (f´(0)) = \frac{\pi}{2}$ so for it to comply, we have to take the transformation as $g (iz)$.
And I conclude that the transformation that performs what I need is:

$w(z)=-\frac{iz+2}{iz-2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need  a minor modification of your function. Take $w(z)=\frac {2+iz} {2-iz}$ This has all the required  properties.

Comment: How is it obtained?

Comment: Your function is same as this except for the missing $i$ in the numerator and the denominator. Your function  has $g'(0)=1$ but we want $g'(0)=i$ so that the argument is $\frac {\pi } 2$. So I just changed $z$ to $iz$ in your function and it worked. @Haus

Comment: Could you check the edit? I got something similar to what you mention, but I don't know if I have any errors

Comment: @Haus It is correct and your function is the same as mine! Just bring the minus sign to the denominator and you will get my function.

Comment: Right, thank you very much.